# What does this Codeigniter command mean?

Tags: php, codeigniter, lambda

I have a question. What does this command mean? Is it if or lambda?

This is the command I'm referring to:

```
$this->user_m->loggedin() == FALSE || redirect($dashboard);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the same thing like this:

```
if ($this->user_m->loggedin() == false) {
    redirect($dashboard);
}
```

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation

Comment: thx. but when i use it normal php it do not work correctly ..so is there this syntax in php? N there is i wanna learn it and what's name this command type